# Issue in AWS Glue devendpoint

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, aws-glue

I m trying to create a new aws glue devendpoint and below is what i get when i try to ssh to the instance.

**MYEC2INSTANCExxxxxx.xxx.compute.amazonaws.com: Permission denied (publickey)**

I m trying to follow the tutorial here:
[https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/dev-endpoint-tutorial-local-](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/dev-endpoint-tutorial-local-notebook.html)notebook.html

I guess the system fails on PORT forwarding.Any help on this ?

Edit:

Below is the full message
I have added xxxx ,where i cannot reveal some data

**Warning: Permanently added 'ec2-xxx-xxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxx' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
glue@ec2-xxxx.xxx.xxx.compute.amazonaws.com: Permission denied (publickey).**

Answer (score 1):

There are two angles for the public key:
1. starts with ---- BEGIN SSH2 PUBLIC KEY ----
2. starts with ssh-rsa AA......
If you use the former, you will get a "Permission denied (public key)"
Use the second one. You can convert or generate a key using PuttyGen

Comment: Hey there!I m doing that already.The key starts with ssh-rsa.I have added some more lines from the error.Please check the post if that helps in figuring out

Comment: You can check two things: 
1.  On your local filesystem, if your private key exists in the given path (preferably path must not have spaces)
2. Check permissions on your Amazon's user role that you used for creation of the dev endpoint